# Paid Google Translator API vs Free Google Translation

Tags: google-translate

I want to use the Google translation service for my website,However i can found many ways and two of them are

1. Paid Google Translator Api
2. Free translation using Http webrequest in C# code (http://translate.google.com/translate_t + parameters)

I have seen that there is a limit of input text characters in paid method(1300 in GET method ,5000 in POST method) where as in Free method there is no limit.

So free method seems to be better and its the only method that meets my requirement,then why i need to use the paid version?